# How can I fix this spidev time out error?

Tags: python, led, spi

I am writing a Python class that will combine control of two different types of RGB LED "pixel" strands from a RPi. You can see all of my code [here on Github](https://github.com/bobtiki/Lava-Lounge/tree/master/tikinook). I will quote the relevant code here, but if you want to look at the everything, it's available there.

I'm running on a Raspberry Pi 2, if that matters.

When I run the tests at the end of `superpixel.py` with one strand of each type in the superset, I get this error:

```
$ sudo python superpixel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "superpixel.py", line 196, in <module>
    strand.begin()
  File "superpixel.py", line 63, in begin
    self.show()
  File "superpixel.py", line 68, in show
    strand.show()
  File "/home/pi/Lava-Lounge/tikinook/paleopixel.py", line 100, in show
    spidev.close()
IOError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Walking backwards, here is `superpixel.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import time

import neopixel
import paleopixel

# SuperPixel
# Author:  Mark Boszko
#
# Combines both NeoPixels and PaleoPixels (WS2801) into a single addressable
# SuperPixel type. Also allows merging of separate pixel strands into one
# master strand or array.


# My LED strip configurations (for test):
NEOPIXEL_COUNT   = 244   # Number of NeoPixels in the strand
NEOPIXEL_PIN     = 18    # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (must support PWM!)
PALEOPIXEL_COUNT = 50    # Number of PaleoPixels in the strand

#####
# 
# SuperPixel - superset pixel strand class
# 
#####

def Color(red, green, blue):
    """Convert the provided red, green, blue color to a 24-bit color value.
    Each color component should be a value 0-255 where 0 is the lowest intensity
    and 255 is the highest intensity.
    """
    return ((red & 0xFF) << 16) | ((green & 0xFF) << 8) | (blue & 0xFF)

class SuperPixel(object):
    def __init__(self, *strands):
        """Class to represent a superset of both neopixel and paleopixel strands

        strands - Variable argument list of sub-strands which should make up
                  the one SuperPixel strand. The sub-strands are added to the
                  super-strand in the order the arguments are listed.
        """
        self._strands = strands
        pixel_count = 0
        for strand in self._strands:
            pixel_count = pixel_count + strand.numPixels()

        # Create an array for all of the LED color data
        self._led_data = [0] * pixel_count

    def __del__(self):
        # Clean up memory used by the library when not needed anymore.
        if self._led_data is not None:
            self._led_data = None
        if self._strands is not None:
            self._strands = None

    def begin(self):
        """Initialize _led_data to zeroes and set up NeoPixels
        """
        for strand in self._strands:
            strand.begin()
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        """Update the display with the data from the LED buffer."""
        for strand in self._strands:
            strand.show()

    def setPixelColor(self, n, color):
        """Set LED at position n to the provided 24-bit color value (in RGB order).
        """
        if (n >= len(self._led_data)):
            return  # out of bounds; throw it away

        # SuperPixel internal representation:
        self._led_data[n] = color

        # Now also set it in the sub-strand
        pixel_offset = 0
        pixel_max    = 0
        for strand in self._strands:
        # TODO: Determine which strand this pixel is a part of, and set it.
            pixel_max = pixel_offset + strand.numPixels()
            if (pixel_offset <= n) and (n < pixel_max):
                pixel = n - pixel_offset
                strand.setPixelColor(pixel, color)
                break
            else:  # Must be in the next one
                pixel_offset = pixel_offset + strand.numPixels()

    def setPixelColorRGB(self, n, red, green, blue):
        """Set LED at position n to the provided red, green, and blue color.
        Each color component should be a value from 0 to 255 (where 0 is the
        lowest intensity and 255 is the highest intensity).
        """
        self.setPixelColor(n, Color(red, green, blue))

    def getPixels(self):
        """Return an object which allows access to the LED display data as if 
        it were a sequence of 24-bit RGB values.
        """
        return self._led_data

    def numPixels(self):
        """Return the number of pixels in the display."""
        return len(self._led_data)

    def getPixelColor(self, n):
        """Get the 24-bit RGB color value for the LED at position n."""
        return self._led_data[n]



#####
# 
# Test functions which animate LEDs in various ways.
# 
#####

def colorWipe(strip, color, wait_ms=50):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

def theaterChase(strip, color, wait_ms=50, iterations=10):
    """Movie theater marquee style chaser animation."""
    for j in range(iterations):
        for q in range(3):
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, color)
            strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0)

def wheel(pos):
    """Generate rainbow colors across 0-255 positions."""
    if pos < 85:
        return Color(pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3, 0)
    elif pos < 170:
        pos -= 85
        return Color(255 - pos * 3, 0, pos * 3)
    else:
        pos -= 170
        return Color(0, pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3)

def rainbow(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=1):
    """Draw rainbow that fades across all pixels at once."""
    for j in range(256*iterations):
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, wheel((i+j) & 255))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

def rainbowCycle(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=5):
    """Draw rainbow that uniformly distributes itself across all pixels."""
    for j in range(256*iterations):
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

def theaterChaseRainbow(strip, wait_ms=50):
    """Rainbow movie theater marquee style chaser animation."""
    for j in range(256):
        for q in range(3):
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, wheel((i+j) % 255))
            strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0)



#####      
#      
# Let's test it out!
#
#####

# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create pixel strands with appropriate configuration.
    strand1 = neopixel.Adafruit_NeoPixel(NEOPIXEL_COUNT, NEOPIXEL_PIN)
    strand2 = paleopixel.PaleoPixel(PALEOPIXEL_COUNT)

    # Combine them into one SuperPixel strand
    strand = SuperPixel(strand1, strand2)

    # Intialize the SuperPixel strand (must be called once, before other 
    # functions, if the SuperPixel strand contains any NeoPixels)
    strand.begin()

    print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
    while True:
        # Color wipe animations.
        colorWipe(strand, Color(255, 0, 0))  # Red wipe
        colorWipe(strand, Color(0, 255, 0))  # Blue wipe
        colorWipe(strand, Color(0, 0, 255))  # Green wipe
        # Theater chase animations.
        theaterChase(strand, Color(127, 127, 127))  # White theater chase
        theaterChase(strand, Color(127,   0,   0))  # Red theater chase
        theaterChase(strand, Color(  0,   0, 127))  # Blue theater chase
        # Rainbow animations.
        rainbow(strand)
        rainbowCycle(strand)
        theaterChaseRainbow(strand)
```

And here is the first half of `paleopixel.py` (excluding tests):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
"""
Adafruit NeoPixel library port to control the older WS2801 pixels from 
  Raspberry Pi hardware SPI. Includes Adafruit “strandtest”-style functions
  and performs a self-test if run as main.


Author: Mark Boszko

Raspberry Pi SPI driver code for WS2801 pixels based on Adafruit_LEDpixels.py
https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code

Python port of NeoPixel library based on the rpi_ws281x library port,
  by Tony DiCola and Jeremy Garff
https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x


Usage:

You'll need to translate 3.3V SPI logic levels from the Raspberry Pi to 5V.
Several options are possible, and I have a suggested circuit on my blog post
that describes this project in more detail:

http://stationinthemetro.com/2016/02/27/tiki-nook-build-part-2-raspberry-pi-led-control

- Connect the RPi's MOSI output to the SDI (Serial Data Input) on the WS2801s
- Connect the RPi SCLK clock output to CKI (ClocK Input) on the WS2801
- The RPi's 5V pins will probably not be enough to power a string of
    any significant length. Use an external power supply of appropriate amperage
- Be sure to connect the RPi ground to the LED strip's ground


License:

Licensed under The MIT License (MIT). Please see LICENSE.txt for full text
of the license.


Version History:

- 1.0.1 - 2016-02-29 - Changed license from CC-BY-4.0 to MIT, due to 
                       recommendation by Creative Commons not to apply their 
                       licenses to software. See CC's FAQ for details:
                       https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software
- 1.0   - 2016-02-27 - Started development and complete rewrite, all in the 
                       same day!

"""


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os


# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 50      # Number of LED pixels.

#####
# 
# PaleoPixel - NeoPixel library port for WS2801 control over RPi hardware SPI
# 
#####

def Color(red, green, blue):
    """Convert the provided red, green, blue color to a 24-bit color value.
    Each color component should be a value 0-255 where 0 is the lowest intensity
    and 255 is the highest intensity.
    """
    return ((red & 0xFF) << 16) | ((green & 0xFF) << 8) | (blue & 0xFF)

class PaleoPixel(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        """Class to represent a WS2801 LED display.

        num - number of pixels in the display.
        """
        # Create an array for the LED data
        self._led_data = [0] * num

    def __del__(self):
        # Clean up memory used by the library when not needed anymore.
        if self._led_data is not None:
            self._led_data = None

    def begin(self):
        """Initialize _led_data to zeroes.
        Not necessary, since we do this in __init__, but handy.
        """
        for i in range(len(self._led_data)):
            self._led_data[i] = 0
        self.show()

    def show(self):
        """Update the display with the data from the LED buffer."""
        spidev = file("/dev/spidev0.0", "w")
        for i in range(len(self._led_data)):
            spidev.write(chr((self._led_data[i]>>16) & 0xFF))
            spidev.write(chr((self._led_data[i]>>8) & 0xFF))
            spidev.write(chr(self._led_data[i] & 0xFF))
        spidev.close()
        time.sleep(0.002)

    def setPixelColor(self, n, color):
        """Set LED at position n to the provided 24-bit color value (in RGB order).
        """
        if (n >= len(self._led_data)):
            return
        self._led_data[n] = color

    def setPixelColorRGB(self, n, red, green, blue):
        """Set LED at position n to the provided red, green, and blue color.
        Each color component should be a value from 0 to 255 (where 0 is the
        lowest intensity and 255 is the highest intensity).
        """
        self.setPixelColor(n, Color(red, green, blue))

    def getPixels(self):
        """Return an object which allows access to the LED display data as if 
        it were a sequence of 24-bit RGB values.
        """
        return self._led_data

    def numPixels(self):
        """Return the number of pixels in the display."""
        return len(self._led_data)

    def getPixelColor(self, n):
        """Get the 24-bit RGB color value for the LED at position n."""
        return self._led_data[n]
```

I should note that `paleopixel.py` tests fine on its own, and if I test `superpixel.py` with one strand (of either type), it works fine. In fact, if I test with two strands of the same type, it also works fine. It's only with one strand of each type that it fails with `IOError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`.

Is it possible to extend the timeout length for the `spidev` write? I admit I am not super familiar with SPI, but I tried to dig into the docs, and couldn't find anything. Or would there be a faster way to write out the bits, so that it doesn't time out? (Just making guesses at a solution.)

Comment: I didn't really read the code (I'm not a python user) but have you tried re-trying in a loop with a 1s gap a few times?  Not that this will necessarily solve your problem, but it will narrow the nature of it down a bit.

Comment: @goldilocks Which action(s) are you suggesting that I put in the loop? I'm not sure that I follow.

Comment: There's an IO connection timeout; again I'm not a python user but this is passes through from a lower level (C) and you need to isolate 1) Exactly what command that is; 2) If gapping/retrying a bit helps.  Like I said, it is not a *solution*, but it is a means of digging

Comment: Sorry -- "digging" should have been "debugging" (I'm on a phone and editing the post seems impossible on the SE app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine suggested I try to remove a layer of abstraction (the Python file handlers), and do this with PaleoPixel.show()

```
class PaleoPixel(object):
    [...]

    def show(self):
        """Update the display with the data from the LED buffer."""
        # Trying to use the os access directly, instead of going through the
        # Python file code. Suggestion by Mike Ash.
        spidev = os.open('/dev/spidev0.0', os.O_WRONLY)
        for i in range(len(self._led_data)):
            os.write(spidev, chr((self._led_data[i]>>16) & 0xFF))
            os.write(spidev, chr((self._led_data[i]>>8) & 0xFF))
            os.write(spidev, chr(self._led_data[i] & 0xFF))
        os.close(spidev)
        time.sleep(0.002)
        # This works, for the most part, but there is some flickering
        # in the PaleoPixel strand when used inside a SuperPixel set
```

While it is not as perfectly smooth as I would like it to be (I may also try it using [python-spidev](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spidev) to see if that improves the speed), it does at least answer my original question, and gets rid of the time-out error.